# report builder for django

Tags: python, django, reporters

is this something like **stimulsoft** or **crystal report** for **django**, i am not talking about report viewer that just *export* some excel data, i am talking about whole package, like some text with *variables* and some tables, pages with *headers* and *footers* and water marks and so on.

> i want to have footer on every page and tables that i don't know how
> long they will grow and maybe they go to second page or third and the
> page must be generated with footer for new data just like stimulsoft
> reporter

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Questions asking us to recommend tools, packages, or any other off-site resources, etc. are _off-topic_ for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reportlab that contains such features. [[read it!]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/outputting-pdf/). But I don't found a full package to connect models and making reports. In Reportlab you can make page templates and complete them with data. For the Persian language, you should use external packages for RTL reshaping.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ReportBro](https://pypi.org/project/reportbro-lib/)

Commercial use requires a license. I'm not affiliated, but currently evaluating for use in my own project. It seems to offer everything you're looking for.

Comment: tnx man i will check it out for sure, i use some reportlab and it is hard to use for simple project and then i switch to create node server for stimulsoft and then use the response pdf on my django app, nice to have all in one package with designer